# In Excel, need cell to display content of another cell only if a 3rd tell holds true to a statement

Tags: excel

In Excel, I need a cell to display the content of a 2nd cell only if a 3rd cell is true to a statement but if it is not, I want it to display the content of a different cell or, in some cases, not display anything. The best way to explain this is for me to give an example of what I want.

For an example: I want C1 to display nothing only if A1 is less than or equal to 5. However, if A1 is greater than 5 but less than or equal to 10, then I want C1 to display the content of B1, and if A1 is greater than 10 but less than or equal to 15, I want C1 to display the contents of B2, and so on.

Is there any possible way of doing this? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: It is possible. Show us what you have tried. SO is a great place to get help, not asking others to do what you want.

Comment: Well I'm not super knowledgeable about excel. Just know what I have learned from using it and from googling things I didn't know how to do. When I searched for an answer, I came up with trying to use the IF function but from what I've tried that only allows me to display text, not the content of another cell, unless I did something wrong. So then I tried possibly using the LOOKUP function within the IF function but again (at least the way I did it) it didn't recognize it as a function, only as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, following is the formula that you can use -

=IF(A1>5,IF(A1>10,IF(A1>15,B2,B1),A1),"")

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! I thought I tried it but maybe I didn't do the nesting correctly. This will definitely get me going in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had to check a value over multiple cells. 
If any of the 3 cells `=6` then the value `=75`, otherwise it was the value of another calculated field.  Thought this might be helpful to others.

```
   =IF((OR(A2=6,B2=6,C2=6)),75,H2)
```